# How to save Bitmap Image in Android device through code written in C++

Tags: java, android, c++, ofstream

I'm trying to save a bitmap image in the Android but through C++ functionality. Do I use ofstream? And if yes, what path should I give for the ofstream object created?

```
std::ofstream bmpF;
bmpF.open(<Android Path?>, std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::out);
```

Answer (score 0):

fileName can be any path in android project. You can pass it through jni layer and get same in java from : context.getFilesDir() +"/"+

As far as use of ofstream: you may choose to write to file in same way as you would in normal c/c++ project.

Text file example

```
void writeToFile( const char* fileName) {
    FILE* fid = fopen(fileName, "w");
    if (fid==NULL) {
        printf("WriteVectorArt: couldn't open the file");
    } else {
        fprintf(fid, "SomeText to write");
        fclose(fid);
   }}
```

Answer (score -1):

bmpF.open("//storage//emulated//0//pictures//name.bmp", std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::out);